# Vue 3 setInterval Methods behavior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

## Env

I have a Vue 3 Application which requires a constant `setInterval()` to be running in the background (Game Loop).

I put that in `store/index.js` and call it from `views/Playground.vue` on `mounted()`.
When leaving `Playground` i call `beforeUnmount()`. Making sure that not multiple `setInterval()` are running.

```js
// store/index.js
startGameLoop({ commit, dispatch, getters }) {
  commit(
    "setIntervalId",
    setInterval(() => {
      dispatch("addPower", getters["ship/getFuelPerSecond"]);
    }, 1000)
  );
},

// Playground.vue
beforeUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

In the top section of `Playground.vue` there is a score displayed and updated within the `setInterval()`. I use a library called `gsap` to make the changing numbers a bit pleasant for the eye.

```html
<h2>Points: {{ tweened.toFixed(0) }}</h2>
```

```js
watch: {
  points(n) {
    console.log("gsap");
    gsap.to(this, { duration: 0.2, tweened: Number(n) || 0 });
  },
},
```

## Problem

`methods` from the `Playground.vue` are fired differently and i'm struggling to understand why that is the case.

##### gsap

the `watch` from the `gsap` is fired every second like i would expect from the `setInterval()` but...

##### Image

In the center of the Playground i display and image where the `src` part is `v-bind` to a method called `getEnemyShipImage`. In the future i would like to change the displayed enemie ship programmatically - but the method is called **34** times per second. Why is that?

```js
<img
   :class="{ flashing: flash }"
   @click="fightEnemie()"
   :src="getEnemyShipImage()"
   alt=""
/>

getEnemyShipImage() {
   console.log("image");
   return require("@/assets/ships/ship-001.png");
}
```

##### Log (Browser)

[Console Log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kymeX.png)

Comment: Why is getEnemyShipImage a method? It's called on each render, for one reason or another. In your case this is at least partially because you use gsap on reactive properties. I doubt that updating DOM very often is worth it.

Comment: if i want to update the displayed images programmatically - should'nt i use a method for that?

Comment: It can be done in several ways, a method is least preferable because it has no optimizations. If it's the same image every time, it should be costant data then.

Comment: i think there's no way to do that. array[3 images] cannot access any of them without using a method because binding the images to :src needs `require` and this seems not to work in the context of :src so it needs to be put in a method. back to the initial problem

Comment: Old question but I stumbled upon it. First: why aren't you using a computed value (or is it really depending on Math.random?)? And regarding the 34 udpates: Are you testing inside your Vue dev server? This might lead to unexpected bahaviour with intervals and auto reloading.

Comment: late reply sorry: i want to display some random images so Math.random was first choice other ideas are welcome. yes i was testing in dev env but i worked after the changes below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved it to a part without using a `method` and switch changing images to a `watch`.

```js
data: () => {
  return {
    ...
    selectedImages: "",
    images: [
      require("@/assets/ships/ship-001.png"),
      require("@/assets/ships/ship-002.png"),
      require("@/assets/ships/ship-003.png"),
    ],
  };
},

// initial value
mounted() {
  this.selectedImages =
    this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)];
  this.$store.dispatch("startGameLoop");
}

// watch score
watch: {
    score() {
    this.selectedImages =
      this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)];
  },
}
```

it's not perfect but better as initialy.